# Combining columns in a complex pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this table:

#### INPUT

[image: Input]

I wish to transform it into another table, that contains

- The Date/Id/Order columns (primary key columns)
- A TotalCount column, containing the value of the original table's Count column where all the Cond columns are NULL
- One Count column for each CondX column, containing the value of the original table's Count column where CondX = 1 and the rest of the Cond = NULL
- One Count column for each combination of non-null (Cond1 OR Cond2 OR Cond3) + (CondA OR CondB), containing the value of the original table's Count column where the two applicable Cond = 1 and the rest = NULL

#### Example:

[image: Data treatment]

So basically, I want my new table to have these columns:

- Date, Id, Order, TotalCount
- Cond1Count, Cond2Count, Cond3Count, CondACount, CondBCount
- Cond1AndCondACount, Cond1AndCondBCount, Cond2AndCondACount, Cond2AndCondBCount...

From the sample image, we'd have these values in the end:

#### DESIRED OUTPUT

[image: OutputData]

*(note: CondBCount = 0 for Order = 2, missed it in the image edition)*

I'd show some SQL if I had any, but I'm actually not quite sure where to start with this problem. I could naively do a bunch of different `SELECT Count WHERE ...`, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without your table structure. You can sum multiple columns with sum & values, even in combination with `CASE`
Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Date, Id, [Order], 
        (SELECT SUM(v) 
       FROM (VALUES (ISNULL(Cond1,0)), (ISNULL(Cond2,0)),...) AS value(v)) Cond1ACount
    FROM YourTable
) sub
GROUP BY Date, Id, [Order]
```